# How to use select query with two tables using mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables `users` and `employers` in mysql, I just want to get all records from both tables at same time.

How can I do this using codeigniter ?

Comment: which column having relation in both tables?

Comment: @devpro: there is no relation between these two tables, in both tables there is field "skills" and "entity" so i want to fetch all employers and users whose entity and skills match with search keyword, is this possible ?

Comment: use [union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Comment: @DrakulaPredator : can you explain or write any query so i can implement in my side

Comment: @Anu Please check my answer.

Comment: did u checked the answers??? if issue resolved, then accepting the answer is a good approach for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you don't have relation between both tables, so you can get the data as like this cross join:

```
$this->db->select('users.*,employers.*'); 
$this->db->from('users,employers');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

If you want to use `LIKE` clause then you can just add:

```
$this->db->like('users.entity', $search_keyword_here, "both"); // here both means '%your keyword%'
$this->db->or_like('users.skills', $search_keyword_here, "both"); // here both means '%your keyword%'
```

You can use or_like for employers table also.

Note that, when we use cross join it will produce result like `(users no of rows *employers no of rows)`

[CI Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

[CI Database Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html)

Comment: i want to get records with "search keyword", so where is "like" in your query ? kindly write complete query

Comment: your code searching keyword with one table, you mean to say that i have to use same like query with employer table also ? right ?

Comment: `Note that, when we use cross join it will produce result like (users no of rows *employers no of rows)` i have already mentioned this, now atleast u can fetch the desired result, isnit? @Anu

Answer (score 0):

> Try this sql query

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2....(put all tables and columns name that you want to join)
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;
```

> [or go to this site]
>
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm